# CS50 Pset 2 Caesar --- Validating the key

Tags: c, loops, cs50, caesar-cipher

Trying to get this code to reject 20x (and other similar inputs). It rejects xyz and x2 however not 20x. Seems there's an issue with my loop...

Any advice?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

bool is_digit (string s);

int main (int argc, string argvc[]) {
    if (argc != 2 || !is_digit(argvc[1]))
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Success\n");
        printf("%s\n", argvc[1]);
    }
}

bool is_digit(string s) { 
    int n = strlen (s);
    for (int i=0; i < n ; i++)
    {
        char x = s[i];
        if (!isdigit(x))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly your function is doing? How it verifies if the character is a digit? I suggest you use the isdigit() function. Just include the header file ctype.h.

Comment: I have included the isdigit() function.

Answer (score 0):

The `is_digit` function tests the first character of s, and then returns to main. A return ends the function, therefore the `for` loop does not continue iterating.